# LaTex Error Help- Math Related

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make an equation array

```
\begin{eqnarray*}  
f^{(a)} (0) &=& \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{f(z)}{(z)^{a+1}} dz &=&   
  &=& \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{z-z^{2}-z^{3}-\dots -z^{n-1}}{(z^{a+1})(1-z-z^{2}-z^{3}-%
\dots -z^{n})} dz   
\end{eqnarray*}%
```

Everything appears to be fine except there's an extra `=`  sign to the far right and I can't seem to find any way to get rid of it. Any help would be very appreciated!

**Addendum**: I'm having trouble formatting this

```
\begin{align*}  
$$f_a = Res (F(z))_{z=0}   
&= \Big(Res(F(z)_{z=0} +\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta)\Big) - \Big(\sum_{\beta}   \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta))     
&= {2\pi i}\oint F(z)dz -  \Big(\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta)\Big)   
&= - \Big(\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\rho)\beta) $$   
\end{align}%
```

The whole thing is simply staying in one line instead of breaking up into the proper formatting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @Mico I figured out that portion, but I'm having another alignment issue.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Now that you have posted a follow-up question, maybe you can take out the new formatting issue part from your question. `:-)`

Comment: Remove `$$`...`$$` from within your `align*` and you also need a line-break `\\` at the end of every equation.

Answer (score 9):

You are missing `\\` to finish your first line.

[image: screenshot]

I would recommend using `align` from the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) package instead of `eqnarray` which is considered obsolete as detailed in [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) The `align` environment gives much better spacing.

A complete MWE follows, including the implementation of `align`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{original using eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray*}  
    f^{(a)} (0) &=& \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{f(z)}{(z)^{a+1}} dz \\
                &=& \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{z-z^{2}-z^{3}-\dots -z^{n-1}}{(z^{a+1})(1-z-z^{2}-z^{3}- \dots -z^{n})} dz   
\end{eqnarray*}%

\subsection*{new-- recommended using align}
\begin{align*}  
    f^{(a)} (0) & = \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{f(z)}{(z)^{a+1}} dz                                                        \\
                & = \frac{a!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{ |z| = \frac{\varepsilon}{r}} \frac{z-z^{2}-z^{3}-\dots -z^{n-1}}{(z^{a+1})(1-z-z^{2}-z^{3}- \dots -z^{n})} dz 
\end{align*}%

\end{document}
```

Here's a possible solution for your follow-up question- note that I have used `\DeclareMathOperator` as described by @Mico

Put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{Res}
```

and then you can use `\res` as follows:

```
\subsection*{Follow-up question}
\begin{align*}  
    f_a & = \res{(F(z))}_{z=0}                                                                                           \\
        & = \Big(\res{(F(z)}_{z=0} +\sum_{\beta} \res{(F(z))},z=\beta)\Big) - \Big(\sum_{\beta}   \res{(F(z))},z=\beta)) \\
        & = {2\pi i}\oint F(z)dz -  \Big(\sum_{\beta} \res{(F(z))},z=\beta)\Big)                                         \\
        & = - \Big(\sum_{\beta} \res{(F(z))},z=\rho)\beta)                                                               \\
\end{align*}%
```

Note that the issue with your code in this case was, as before, the lack of `\\` to illustrate a new line.

Comment: Could you help me with my updated question?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter please see Mico's comment :)

Comment: I have figured out what the problem was. Now I'm having another alignment issue.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

This answer addresses your follow-up question only; I believe @cmhughes has already fully answered the original question.

There are several problems with your code; the first two items in the following list have already been pointed out by @Werner.

- One must terminate each line of intended output with a `\\` (double backslash);
- the `align` and `align*` environments already put TeX into displaymath mode -- don't provide `$$` directives as well;
- be sure to type `\end{align*}` rather than `\end{align}` -- the two environments are *not* the same;
- when you have `\Big(` directives, take care to type `\Big)` rather than just `)` to end the parenthetical expression. Better yet, use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`;
- you use `\text{Res}` in some cases but just `Res` in others, leading to inconsistent typeset appearance of the string. Since "Res" is an operator name (as are "sin" and "log", say), you could define a macro `\Res` to typeset "Res" in upright letters consistently. I suggest you include the instruction

  ```
  \DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
  ```

  in the preamble -- after loading the `amsmath` package, which provides the `\DeclareMathOperator` command -- and then use `\Res` throughout the math expressions of your document.

Comment: `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` is preferable to keep the opening and closing atom nature of the parentheses. And `\textrm` is redundant with `\DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: @egreg -- thanks! I'll change my write-up.

Comment: I have deleted my answer in the dupe and upvoted this. This answer is more complete than my deleted answer. :-)