# Alignment Issues in Equations

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTex Error Help- Math Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95517/latex-error-help-math-related)

I'm having trouble formatting this

```
\begin{align*}  
$$f_a = Res (F(z))_{z=0}   
&= \Big(Res(F(z)_{z=0} +\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta)\Big) - \Big(\sum_{\beta}   \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta))     
&= {2\pi i}\oint F(z)dz -  \Big(\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\beta)\Big)   
&= - \Big(\sum_{\beta} \text{Res}(F(z)),z=\rho)\beta) $$   
\end{align}%
```

The whole thing is simply staying in one line instead of breaking up into the proper formatting.

Comment: In adition to hpesoj626 's answer, you should balance the size of your parentheses.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Thanks for noting. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Since you have not modified your previous post, I agree that this is a duplicate. I have deleted my answer and voted to close this question. Upon closer inspection, @Mico provided a complete answer to your update in your previous post.